# With CoreText, how do I reset coordinates to draw more text

Tags: xamarin, core-text

I using CoreText to draw to a CGBitmapContext.  I found a great example on StackOverflow that centers text using GetBounds and TranslateCTM, and this works great for me.

However, if I try to add a 2nd text element, I can't predictably reset the coordinates and can't find any useful documentation.  I can draw either text element, but not both, as the 2nd always appears in the wrong place.

I have tried calling SaveState at the start and RestoreState after drawing the first text.  I don't think this does anything as far as coordinates.  I’ve also tried MoveTo(0,0) which also doesn’t seem to do anything either.

I can call TranslateCTM again, which at least seems to do something.  I don’t know if this transform is relative to the previous time it was called, or sets the translation matrix to absolute coordinates, but am guessing it is relative based on what I’ve seen.  TranslateCTM(0,0) doesn’t seem to do anything.  TranslateCTM using 0 - the values I used to center the text seems to put my cursor to the right of the last text I drew, but a larger negative offset doesn’t seem to take it left of where my previous text ended.

How do I reset my transform and coordinates back to the way they started?

Comment: *"I found a great example on StackOverflow"* - please give **link** to that example. This will provide context for what you are asking. Also, **add to question your code.** Don't just describe what you did in code. Show exactly what the code looked like when you added a 2nd text. Its also extremely useful to say **exactly what goes wrong**. Instead of **2nd always appears in wrong place**, show specific code, and specifically where 2nd ends up with that code.

Comment: Also, what is the desired end result? Taking what you say literally, it sounds like you want the 2nd text drawn directly on top of the 1st text. Do you really mean that?

Comment: While not relevant to this question, if interested in Xamarin 2D text and graphics that will work on other platforms (not just MacOS and iOS), consider using `SkiaSharp` in Xamarin.

Comment: Desired result is to reset the coordinates, or even better, understand how to reset them.